# Laravel - url parameters after?

Tags: laravel

in Laravel, I want to be able to search user by id, or by name.

I have following route:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', 'UserController@getUserById')->name('user_by_id');
```

which in browser looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/user/1
```

As you can see, from the url it is not possible to determine, if passed value is id or name.

So, what I am asking for are probably url parameters after `?` symbol.

I want to have following urls:

```
http://localhost:8000/user?id=1
http://localhost:8000/user?name=hans
```

but I have never found someone even mentioning this problem.

Is this possible ?
If not, or of it is not best practice, how to handle this properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this would be best practice but something like this should do the trick:

```php
public function getUserById($id)
{  
    $user = User::where('id', $id)->orWhere('name', $id)->first();

    $data['user'] = $user;

    return view('...',  $data);
}
```

---

**Edit**, now that i know is an index view.. you can also do the following:

Change your route to:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@getUserById')->name('user_by_id');
```

Now you can use the route like `http://...user?id=1&name=someSome`

I would change the function name but thats up to you...

```php
public function getUserById()
{
    $q = User::query();

    if($request->id){
        $q->where('id', $request->id);
    }

    if($request->name){
        $q->where('name', $request->name);
    }

    $data['users'] = $q->get();

    return view('...',  $data);
}
```

Take into account that this would return everything in case no parameter is set

Comment: Quick tip, you can replace `get()->first()` by `first()`, `get()` returns a collection on which you call the `first()` function, calling `first()` directly on the query changes the actual sql query and only fetches the first result which is also less memory intensive.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about something like this, but what about if multiple database fields have the same value ? You know - if i would have wanted to search by name or surname instead. This would return first user, but there would be multiple results from database...

Comment: what kind of view is this, a list/index ? or a data/show view?

Comment: if this is a "show" view, i would not use this method i would always use ID...  but if this is some kind of index, you could just use `get()` ...

Comment: I want the data to be in html table, so multiple results would still be rendered, but I just wanted to know the best practice.

Comment: Its an index view... best practice is manage it on an api with post parameters (which might be overkill for your needs) or the most common, use get attributes.

Comment: @milkamar i added an edit, that may fit more to what you need

Answer (score 1):

You could create a route in which you get the `id` variable and do a `where` clause on both id and name.

```
public function getUserById(Request $request, $id){
    $users = User::where('name', $id)->orWhere('id', $id')->get();
}
```

If you want to use url parameters you can also use the `$request->input()` function.

```
http://localhost:8000/user?id=1&name=milo

public function getUserById(Request $request){
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $name = $request->input('name');
}
```